# How to install wp-Calypso on Windows

Tags: node.js, wordpress, cygwin, wp-calypso

I am trying to install wp-calypso on windows found from here: https://github.com/Automattic/wp-calypso

I have clone from `git clone https://github.com/Automattic/wp-calypso.git`
Added `127.0.0.1 calypso.localhost` to your local hosts file successfully but make run command not working for me I am using Cygwin terminal for run command.

Can any one know how can I run make command so that I can continue with it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Recently, a [PR got merged](https://github.com/Automattic/wp-calypso/pull/2124) that added Windows support to wp-calypso. Please follow carefully [these official instructions](https://github.com/Automattic/wp-calypso/blob/master/docs/windows.md) and you should be all set!

You need to install MSYS2 in addition to all the normal dependencies, but we need all the *nix tools it provides (and most importantly - an up to date version of `make`).